# Spirit Grammar To break Up a String by Number of Characters

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I am working on learning to write spirit grammars and I am trying to create a basic base 16 to base 64 converter that takes in a string representing hex, for example:

```
49276d206b696c
```

parse out 6 or less characters (less if the string isn't a perfect multiple of 6) and generate a base 64 encoded string from the input. One grammar I figured would probably work is something like this:

```
// 6 characters 
`(qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >> qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >> 
 qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >> qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >>
 qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >> qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F")[/*action*/]) | 


// or 5 characters
(qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >> qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >> 
qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >> qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F") >> 
qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F")[/*action*/]) | ...`
```

etc.... all the way down to one character, Or having a different rule defined for each number of characters, but I think there must be a better way to specify the grammar. I read about spirit repeat and was thinking maybe I could do something like 
`+(boost::spirit::repeat(1, 6)[qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F")][/*action on characters*/])` 
however the compiler throws an error on this, because of the sematic action portion of the grammar. Is there a simpler way to specify a grammar to operate on exactly 6 or less characters at a time?

**Edit**
Here is what I have done so far...
base16convertergrammar.hpp

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>    

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace grammar {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    void toBase64(const std::string& p_input, std::string& p_output)
    {   
        if (p_input.length() < 6)
        {   
            // pad length
        }   

        // use back inserter and generator to append to end of p_output.
    }   

    template <typename Iterator>
    struct Base16Grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string()>
    {
        Base16Grammar() : Base16Grammar::base_type(start, "base16grammar"),
            m_base64String()
        {
            // get six characters at a time and send them off to be encoded
            // if there is less than six characters just parse what we have
            start = +(boost::spirit::repeat(1, 6)[qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F")][boost::phoenix::bind(toBase64, qi::_1,
                boost::phoenix::ref(m_base64String))]);
        }

        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> start;

        std::string m_base64String;
    };
}
```

And here is the usage... 
base16converter.cpp

```
#include "base16convertergrammar.hpp"

const std::string& convertHexToBase64(const std::string& p_hexString)
{
    grammar::Base16Grammar<std::string::const_iterator> g;
    bool r = boost::spirit::qi::parse(p_hexString.begin(), p_hexString.end(), g); 
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string test("49276d206b696c6c");
    convertHexToBase64(test);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's an error while transcribing, but in your examples the semantic actions are only attached to the last of your chars ignoring the rest. The alternative you propose should work, having an attribute of `vector<char>`. It would be easier (and better for you) if you provided a (-n almost) complete example.

Comment: I added what I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `repeat()[]` exposes a vector, so `vector<char>`, not a string.

```
void toBase64(const std::vector<char>& p_input, std::string& p_output)
```

Secondly, please don't do all that work. You don't tell us what the input means, but as long as you want to group it in sixes, I'm assuming you want them interpreted as /something/. You could e.g. use the int_parser:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7de538b6320e7ca)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>    

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace grammar {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace px = boost::phoenix;

    template <typename Iterator>
    struct Base16Grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string()>
    {
        Base16Grammar() : Base16Grammar::base_type(start, "base16grammar")
        {
            start = +qi::int_parser<uint64_t, 16, 1, 6>() [ qi::_val += to_string(qi::_1) + "; " ];
        }

      private:
        struct to_string_f { template <typename T> std::string operator()(T const& v) const { return std::to_string(v); } };
        px::function<to_string_f> to_string;

        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> start;
    };
}

std::string convertHexToBase64(const std::string& p_hexString)
{
    grammar::Base16Grammar<std::string::const_iterator> g;
    std::string result;
    bool r = boost::spirit::qi::parse(p_hexString.begin(), p_hexString.end(), g, result); 
    assert(r);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string test : {"49276d206b696c6c"})
        std::cout << test << " -> " << convertHexToBase64(test) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
49276d206b696c6c -> 4794221; 2124649; 27756;
```

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb, you just want to transcode hex-encoded binary into base64.

Since you're already using Boost:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b58ee643a9e338fa)**

```
#include <boost/archive/iterators/base64_from_binary.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/insert_linebreaks.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp>

// for hex decoding
#include <boost/iterator/function_input_iterator.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::string convertHexToBase64(const std::string &hex) {
    struct get_byte_f {
        using result_type = uint8_t;

        std::string::const_iterator hex_it;

        result_type operator()() {
            auto nibble = [](uint8_t ch) {
                if (!std::isxdigit(ch)) throw std::runtime_error("invalid hex input");
                return std::isdigit(ch) ? ch - '0' : std::tolower(ch) - 'a' + 10;
            };

            auto hi = nibble(*hex_it++);
            auto lo = nibble(*hex_it++);
            return hi << 4 | lo;
        }
    } get_byte{ hex.begin() };

    using namespace boost::archive::iterators;

    using It = boost::iterators::function_input_iterator<get_byte_f, size_t>;

    typedef insert_linebreaks<    // insert line breaks every 72 characters
        base64_from_binary<       // convert binary values to base64 characters
            transform_width<      // retrieve 6 bit integers from a sequence of 8 bit bytes
            It, 6, 8> >,
        72> B64;                  // compose all the above operations in to a new iterator

    return { B64(It{get_byte, 0}), B64(It{get_byte, hex.size()/2}) };
}

int main() {
    for (std::string test : {
            "49276d206b696c6c",
            "736f6d65206c656e67746879207465787420746f2073686f77207768617420776f756c642068617070656e206174206c696e6520777261700a"
        })
    {
        std::cout << " === hex: " << test << "\n" << convertHexToBase64(test) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
 === hex: 49276d206b696c6c
SSdtIGtpbGw
 === hex: 736f6d65206c656e67746879207465787420746f2073686f77207768617420776f756c642068617070656e206174206c696e6520777261700a
c29tZSBsZW5ndGh5IHRleHQgdG8gc2hvdyB3aGF0IHdvdWxkIGhhcHBlbiBhdCBsaW5lIHdy
YXAK
```

Comment: That is what I am doing. I actually started this challenge https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1 today and however, I thought just doing a base 64 to base 16 encoder was too easy so I decided to kill two birds with one stone and learn spirit stuff as well.

Comment: thanks for your both of your responses they are both very helpful!